# Self Hosted Training Package/Website Recommendation

Tags: web-applications, software, recommendations

first time poster here, so hope its the right stack exchange.  I'm looking for recommendations for a self hosted software/website that will allow for a company to upload training videos and actually log/verify that an employee watched the videos and maybe took a short quiz.  Integration with WordPress would certainly be ok if that is a recommendation.  Unique user logins would be a requirement needed, but other than that and logging user activity, its still pretty open at this point.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [Learning Management System (LMS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system), preferably one with [SCORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharable_Content_Object_Reference_Model) support so the logging/verification can happen.  For heavy use, I would normally recommend [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) as it has the widest variety of plugins and modules available for SCORM integration and also provides the fine-tuning and configuration options necessary to create a customized learning experience. There is a learning curve involved in getting Moodle up and running, though.

In your particular case I suspect Moodle would be overkill.  WordPress doesn't have a plugin that converts it to a complete LMS solution but you can embed SCORM objects into a WordPress site.  If that's the route you wish to go, then look at the [SCORM Cloud Plugin](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/app-integrations/wordpress-integration/) (and associated 3rd party service to manage the objects/logging).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was unaware of the term "Learning Management System".  This gave me a good starting search phrase!  Thanks, and answer accepted.